# ExtJs Grid Error in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extjs

I still need your help, and more specifically the implementation of the ExtJS grid. 
I can not make it work. 
I have a View that makes a search with more parameters, then the controller will have the action research that when loading the page I set the controls of the latter, and then I post the action through which I search. This is the code:

```
[Authorize (Roles = "OP_Bollettino")]   
02.         [AcceptVerbs (HttpVerbs.Get)]   
03.         Search public ActionResult ()   
04.         (   
05.  
06.  
07.  
08.             Viewdata [ "checksurname"] = "false";   
09.             abilitatosur.Add ( "Disabled" "Disabled");   
10.             Viewdata [ "abilitasur"] = abilitatosur;   
11.             Viewdata [ "checkcf"] = "false";   
12.             abilitatocf.Add ( "Disabled" "Disabled");   
13.             Viewdata [ "abilitacf"] = abilitatocf;   
14.             abilitatocaus.Add ( "Disabled" "Disabled");   
15.             Viewdata [ "checkcausale"] = "false";   
16.             Viewdata [ "abilitacaus"] = abilitatocaus;   
17.             Viewdata [ "selection"] = "Select";   
18.             string EndDate = null;   
19.             string StartDate = null;   
20.             DataFire DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays = (-30);   
21.             EndDate = dataf.ToShortDateString ();   
22.             data = DateTime.Now.Date;   
23.             StartDate = datai.ToShortDateString ();   
24.             Viewdata [ "StartDate"] = EndDate;   
25.             Viewdata [ "EndDate"] = StartDate;   
26.             Viewdata [ "Cause"] = causale.GetListaCausaleDropDown ();   
27.  
28.  
29.  
30.             return View ( "Search");   
31.  
32.  
33.         )   
34.         / / / <summary>   
35.         / / / Implementation of research, and more precisely when the operator clicking on the button passes the parameters   
36.         / / / Will be used to build the Linq query and return the results in the grid.   
37.         / / / </ Summary>   
38.         / / / <param Name="lastname"> </ param>   
39.         / / / <param Name="causale"> </ param>   
40.         / / / <param Name="datainizio"> </ param>   
41.         / / / <param Name="datafine"> </ param>   
42.         / / / <param Name="cf"> </ param>   
43.         / / / <returns> </ Returns>   
44.         [Authorize (Roles = "OP_Bollettino")]   
45.         [AcceptVerbs (HttpVerbs.Post)]   
46.         [LogError]   
47.         public JsonResult Research (FormCollection formcoll)   
48.         (   
49.  
50.             DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays (-30);   
51.             data.ToShortDateString EndDate = string ();   
52.             data.Date.ToShortDateString ();   
53.             string StartDate = DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString ();   
54.  
55.             date = DateTime.Parse (Request.Form [ "StartDate"]. ToString (). Trim ());   
56.  
57.             DataFire = DateTime.Parse (Request.Form [ "EndDate"]. ToString (). Trim ());   
58.             Viewdata [ "StartDate"] = datai.ToShortDateString ();   
59.             Viewdata [ "EndDate"] = dataf.ToShortDateString ();   
60.             TRY   
61.             (   
62.  
63.  
64.                 var search = utente.GetBollettinoBySearch (null, 0, date, DataFire, null);   
65.  
66.  
67.  
68.  
69.                 if (String.IsNullOrEmpty (Request.Form [ "Surname"]))   
70.                 (   
71.                     Viewdata [ "checksurname"] = true;   
72.                     abilitatosur.Add ( "enabled", "enabled");   
73.                     Viewdata [ "abilitasur"] = abilitatosur;   
74.                     Viewdata [ "cog"] = Request.Form [ "Surname"]. Trim (). ("''", Replace "");   
75.                     name = Request.Form [ "Surname"]. Trim (). ("''", Replace "");   
76.                     utente.GetBollettinoBySearch search = (name, 0, date, DataFire, null);   
77.  
78.                 )   
79.                 else  
80.                 (   
81.                     Viewdata [ "checksurname"] = "false";   
82.                     abilitatosur.Add ( "Disabled" "Disabled");   
83.                     Viewdata [ "abilitasur"] = abilitatosur;   
84.  
85.                 )   
86.  
87.  
88.  
89.                 if (String.IsNullOrEmpty (Request.Form [ "Cause"]))   
90.                 (   
91.  
92.                     Viewdata [ "checkcausale"] = "true";   
93.                     abilitatocaus.Add ( "enabled", "enabled");   
94.                     Viewdata [ "abilitacaus"] = abilitatocaus;   
95.                     Viewdata [ "selection"] = "Select";   
96.                     id_causale string = Request.Form [ "Cause"];   
97.  
98.                     utente.GetBollettinoBySearch search = (null, int.Parse (id_causale), date, DataFire, null);   
99.                     var selectcasuale = causale.GetListaCausaleDropDown (). ToList ();   
100.                     Viewdata [ "Reason"] = new SelectList (selectcasuale.ToList (), "Value", "Text", id_causale), / / new MultiSelectList (causale.GetListaCausaleDropDown (), "Value", "Text", selected);   
101.  
102.                 )   
103.                 else  
104.                 (   
105.                     abilitatocaus.Add ( "Disabled" "Disabled");   
106.                     Viewdata [ "checkcausale"] = "false";   
107.                     Viewdata [ "abilitacaus"] = abilitatocaus;   
108.                     Viewdata [ "selection"] = "Select";   
109.                     var selectcausale = causale.GetListaCausaleDropDown (). ToList ();   
110.                     Viewdata [ "Reason"] = new SelectList (selectcausale.ToList (), "Value", "Text", 0);   
111.                 )   
112.  
113.                 if (String.IsNullOrEmpty (Request.Form [ "codiceF"]))   
114.                 (   
115.                     abilitatocf.Add ( "enabled", "enabled");   
116.                     Viewdata [ "abilitacf"] = abilitatocf;   
117.                     Viewdata [ "checkcf"] = true;   
118.                     Viewdata [ "cf"] = Request.Form [ "codiceF"]. Trim (). ("''", Replace "");   
119.                     cf = Request.Form [ "codiceF"]. Trim (). ("''", Replace "");   
120.                     utente.GetBollettinoBySearch search = (null, 0, date, DataFire, cf); / / res.WithCf (cf);   
121.                 )   
122.                 else  
123.                 (   
124.                     Viewdata [ "checkcf"] = "false";   
125.                     abilitatocf.Add ( "Disabled" "Disabled");   
126.                     Viewdata [ "abilitacf"] = abilitatocf;   
127.  
128.                 )   
129.  
130.  
131.  
132.                 return JSON (datastore = new (search));   
133.  
134.  
135.  
136.             )   
137.  
138.             catch (Exception ex)   
139.             (   
140.                 Utilita.LogError (ex);   
141.  
142.                 return JSON ( "Search");   
143.             )   
144.  
145.  
146.         )  
[Authorize (Roles = "OP_Bollettino")]
         [AcceptVerbs (HttpVerbs.Get)]
         Search public ActionResult ()
         (



             Viewdata [ "checksurname"] = "false";
             abilitatosur.Add ( "Disabled" "Disabled");
             Viewdata [ "abilitasur"] = abilitatosur;
             Viewdata [ "checkcf"] = "false";
             abilitatocf.Add ( "Disabled" "Disabled");
             Viewdata [ "abilitacf"] = abilitatocf;
             abilitatocaus.Add ( "Disabled" "Disabled");
             Viewdata [ "checkcausale"] = "false";
             Viewdata [ "abilitacaus"] = abilitatocaus;
             Viewdata [ "selection"] = "Select";
             string EndDate = null;
             string StartDate = null;
             DataFire DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays = (-30);
             EndDate = dataf.ToShortDateString ();
             data = DateTime.Now.Date;
             StartDate = datai.ToShortDateString ();
             Viewdata [ "StartDate"] = EndDate;
             Viewdata [ "EndDate"] = StartDate;
             Viewdata [ "Cause"] = causale.GetListaCausaleDropDown ();



             return View ( "Search");


         )
         / / / <summary>
         / / / Implementation of research, and more precisely when the operator clicking on the button passes the parameters
         / / / Will be used to build the Linq query and return the results in the grid.
         / / / </ Summary>
         / / / <param Name="lastname"> </ param>
         / / / <param Name="causale"> </ param>
         / / / <param Name="datainizio"> </ param>
         / / / <param Name="datafine"> </ param>
         / / / <param Name="cf"> </ param>
         / / / <returns> </ Returns>
         [Authorize (Roles = "OP_Bollettino")]
         [AcceptVerbs (HttpVerbs.Post)]
         [LogError]
         public JsonResult Research (FormCollection formcoll)
         (

             DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays (-30);
             data.ToShortDateString EndDate = string ();
             data.Date.ToShortDateString ();
             string StartDate = DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString ();

             date = DateTime.Parse (Request.Form [ "StartDate"]. ToString (). Trim ());

             DataFire = DateTime.Parse (Request.Form [ "EndDate"]. ToString (). Trim ());
             Viewdata [ "StartDate"] = datai.ToShortDateString ();
             Viewdata [ "EndDate"] = dataf.ToShortDateString ();
             TRY
             (


                 var search = utente.GetBollettinoBySearch (null, 0, date, DataFire, null);




                 if (String.IsNullOrEmpty (Request.Form [ "Surname"]))
                 (
                     Viewdata [ "checksurname"] = true;
                     abilitatosur.Add ( "enabled", "enabled");
                     Viewdata [ "abilitasur"] = abilitatosur;
                     Viewdata [ "cog"] = Request.Form [ "Surname"]. Trim (). ("''", Replace "");
                     name = Request.Form [ "Surname"]. Trim (). ("''", Replace "");
                     utente.GetBollettinoBySearch search = (name, 0, date, DataFire, null);

                 )
                 else
                 (
                     Viewdata [ "checksurname"] = "false";
                     abilitatosur.Add ( "Disabled" "Disabled");
                     Viewdata [ "abilitasur"] = abilitatosur;

                 )



                 if (String.IsNullOrEmpty (Request.Form [ "Cause"]))
                 (

                     Viewdata [ "checkcausale"] = "true";
                     abilitatocaus.Add ( "enabled", "enabled");
                     Viewdata [ "abilitacaus"] = abilitatocaus;
                     Viewdata [ "selection"] = "Select";
                     id_causale string = Request.Form [ "Cause"];

                     utente.GetBollettinoBySearch search = (null, int.Parse (id_causale), date, DataFire, null);
                     var selectcasuale = causale.GetListaCausaleDropDown (). ToList ();
                     Viewdata [ "Reason"] = new SelectList (selectcasuale.ToList (), "Value", "Text", id_causale), / / new MultiSelectList (causale.GetListaCausaleDropDown (), "Value", "Text", selected);

                 )
                 else
                 (
                     abilitatocaus.Add ( "Disabled" "Disabled");
                     Viewdata [ "checkcausale"] = "false";
                     Viewdata [ "abilitacaus"] = abilitatocaus;
                     Viewdata [ "selection"] = "Select";
                     var selectcausale = causale.GetListaCausaleDropDown (). ToList ();
                     Viewdata [ "Reason"] = new SelectList (selectcausale.ToList (), "Value", "Text", 0);
                 )

                 if (String.IsNullOrEmpty (Request.Form [ "codiceF"]))
                 (
                     abilitatocf.Add ( "enabled", "enabled");
                     Viewdata [ "abilitacf"] = abilitatocf;
                     Viewdata [ "checkcf"] = true;
                     Viewdata [ "cf"] = Request.Form [ "codiceF"]. Trim (). ("''", Replace "");
                     cf = Request.Form [ "codiceF"]. Trim (). ("''", Replace "");
                     utente.GetBollettinoBySearch search = (null, 0, date, DataFire, cf); / / res.WithCf (cf);
                 )
                 else
                 (
                     Viewdata [ "checkcf"] = "false";
                     abilitatocf.Add ( "Disabled" "Disabled");
                     Viewdata [ "abilitacf"] = abilitatocf;

                 )



                 return JSON (datastore = new (search));



             )

             catch (Exception ex)
             (
                 Utilita.LogError (ex);

                 return JSON ( "Search");
             )


         )The code to create the extjs grid is as follows: 

view plaincopy to clipboardprint?
function image (val) (   
     return '<img src="' val'" />';   )     
function url (val) (   
     return '<a href="' val.replace("_t.jpg", ".jpg")'" target="_blank"> Click here to download </ a>';   
)     
var store = new Ext.data.Store ((        url: 'Search',   
     reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader ((   
         root: 'datastore',   
         id: 'UserID'  
    )   
[   
'UserID',   
'Name',   
'Name',   
'Way'  
])   

     baseParams: (   
         query:''  
     )   
));   

var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel ((   
     renderTo: 'grid_container',   
     frame: false,   
     border: false,   
     title: 'Search',   
     id: 'grid-search',   
     height: 395,   
     store: store,   
     columns: [   
(Header: "Name", dataIndex: 'Name', width: 120, renderer: image),   
(Header: "Name", dataIndex: 'Name', width: 300, sortable: true),   
(Header: "VIA", dataIndex: 'Via', width: 150, renderer: url)   
]   
));   
function image (val) (
     return '<img src="' val'" />';
)

function url (val) (
     return '<a href="' val.replace("_t.jpg", ".jpg")'" target="_blank"> Click here to download </ a>';
)

var store = new Ext.data.Store ((
     url: 'Search',
     reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader ((
         root: 'datastore',
         id: 'UserID'
     )
[
'UserID',
'Name',
'Name',
'Way'
])

     baseParams: (
         query:''
     )
));

var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel ((
     renderTo: 'grid_container',
     frame: false,
     border: false,
     title: 'Search',
     id: 'grid-search',
     height: 395,
     store: store,
     columns: [
(Header: "Name", dataIndex: 'Name', width: 120, renderer: image),
(Header: "Name", dataIndex: 'Name', width: 300, sortable: true),
(Header: "VIA", dataIndex: 'Via', width: 150, renderer: url)
]
));
```

I have tested a JavaScript debugger and load the page when I enter the debug extjs grid, even though I click the search button to search back to me the contents of the query in notepad format and I do not even enter into debbugger javascript.

I can help you understand why, I tried it with several examples of extjs but does not work.

Thanks

Comment: There is nobody who can help me

Comment: Probably because you should publish only essential part of the code, not the whole.

Answer (score 0):

first you should use a browser to make sure your asp.net app return the proper format.

When you are 100% sure it does, check your ExtJs code.

Kind of generic answer but like Thevs pointed out you shouldn't post such a huge piece of code.

Also would you be able to post the xml or json your asp.net app is returning it would helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hello everyone and thanks for your reply, I solved the problem was that I handed him the correct data from a json extjs